# Start Opera's Find command from the current page location

Tags: search, opera

In the Opera browser when using the Find command to locate something on the current page, it begins its search at the top of the page.

Is there a way force the search to start from the current location of the webpage?

Comment: Try clicking the page's text where you want to start (imagine that the page is a giant editable text box, you can't see the flashing cursor, but it is there). Then try your search. Let me know if it works. I know it does on Chrome.

Comment: This would be a nice, simple workaround if it worked.  Unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [posting](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1404282&t=1337572148&page=1#comment12319992) on Opera's Wishlist forum I got a reply that has the answer.

If you establish your location by *selecting* something on the page, Opera begins its search from that point.  Simply *clicking* somewhere on the page has no effect.

This behavior is not mentioned in Opera's [help page for searching](http://help.opera.com/Linux/11.60/en/search.html).

Opera needs to improve this.  If a feature can only be discovered by posting questions on a forum, the interface has failed.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as solved @user81430. It helps the community.

Comment: Done.  With my current rep, I had to wait a day before I was allowed to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Opera always starts at the top. However, pressing F3 will tell it to continue from the last-found location. Shift-F3 searches backwards from the last found.

You could post a request in [Opera's wishlist](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/forum.dml?id=24).